# How to get share, like, comment and total count from facebook.com/username

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I would like to get share, like, comment and total count from a fan page **facebook.com/username**

Actually if I have a **www.example.com**, I can have these counts using FQL:

- SELECT **total_count, like_count, comment_count, share_count, commentsbox_count, click_count** FROM link_stat WHERE url = 'http://www.example.com/'

But if I have a facebook fan page like this:

**https://www.facebook.com/HuffingtonPost**

Actually I'm able only to have total count:

https://graph.facebook.com/**https://www.facebook.com/HuffingtonPost**

And like count:

https://graph.facebook.com/**HuffingtonPost**

How to get remaining **comment_count, share_count, commentsbox_count and click_count** fields?
Or at least comment_count or share_count :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use: https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=HuffingtonPost

Then parse the results.  The response is json and you can decode that to get the number of 'likes' for example.

That is similar to what you noted, I just wanted to add the "?ids=" as that is how I ran it.

For the other information this could work:

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT+url%2C+normalized_url%2C+share_count%2C+like_count%2C+comment_count%2C+total_count%2C+commentsbox_count%2C+comments_fbid%2C+click_count+FROM+link_stat+WHERE+url%3D"http://www.facebook.com/HuffingtonPost"

Let me know if this resolves what you are after.

Comment: This gives for those values for a url not for the page

Comment: This answer is no longer valid as FQL support has been deprecated.